# How to generate PDF without page break

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

I'm converting my WebView to PDf using following code.

```
 UIWebView *webView = self.webView;
        NSString *heightStr = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"];

        int height = [heightStr intValue];
        //  CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        //  CGFloat screenHeight = (self.contentWebView.hidden)?screenRect.size.width:screenRect.size.height;
        CGFloat screenHeight = webView.bounds.size.height;
            int pages = ceil(height / screenHeight);

        NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, webView.bounds, nil);
        CGRect frame = [webView frame];
        for (int i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
            // Check to screenHeight if page draws more than the height of the UIWebView
            if ((i+1) * screenHeight  > height) {
                CGRect f = [webView frame];
                f.size.height -= (((i+1) * screenHeight) - height);
                f.size.width  = self.webView.bounds.size.width*1.6;
                [webView setFrame: f];
            }

            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
            CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            //      CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 72, 72); // Translate for 1" margins

            [[[webView subviews] lastObject] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, screenHeight * i) animated:NO];
            [webView.layer renderInContext:currentContext];
        }

        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
        // Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
        NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

        NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* documentDirectoryFilename =[documentDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/pdfFile.PDF"] ;

        // instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
        [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
        [webView setFrame:frame];
```

But the issue is its generating PDF with page break as shown in image.
[image]

**I don't want this page break.can any one suggest what should I do.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the page size here

```
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, webView.bounds, nil);
```

currently set to `webView.bounds`

Change it with appropriate value.

Comment: Yeah,It worked i changed webView.bounds with CGRect variable which has height equivalent to webView's ScrollView,And in [[[webView subviews] lastObject] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, screenHeight * i) animated:NO] i changed screenHeight * i with variable height.And i replaced int pages = ceil(height / screenHeight) with int page=1;

Answer (score 0):

This little css worked for me.

```
  @media print {
        .avoid_pagebreak { display: block; page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-before: auto; }
    }
  ...
  <div class="avoid_pagebreak">
  ...
  </div>
```